# How can I get this accomplished?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Below is the data set

```
P1      A1      N1

null    null    0
2776646 2776621 1
2776646 2776622 2
2776642 2776645 3
2776642 2776648 4
2776642 2776649 5
2776642 2776647 6
2776642 2776646 7
0       2776641
0       2776642
```

I need to add another column here which will be called a parent_n1 and it will have the values in N1, which belong to the parent (P1) of A1. For eg:

For A1.2776621 P1 = 2776646 and in A1 2776646 = N1.7, so the parent_n1 for this row becomes 7. Similarly the query should return the following output for every row:

```
P1      A1      N1  Parent_N1

null    null    0   0
2776646 2776621 1   7
2776646 2776622 2   7
2776642 2776645 3   9
2776642 2776648 4   9
2776642 2776649 5   9
2776642 2776647 6   9
2776642 2776646 7   9
0       2776641 8   0
0       2776642 9   0
```

Any help would be appreciated here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can self-join the table:

```
select
    t.*,
    coalesce(p.n1, 0) parent_n1
from mytable t
left join mytable p on p.a1 = t.p1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=47118b96bc781a8c77b1523274b00f4b)**:

```
     P1 |      A1 | N1 | PARENT_N1
------: | ------: | -: | --------:
   null |    null |  0 |         0
2776646 | 2776621 |  1 |         7
2776646 | 2776622 |  2 |         7
2776642 | 2776645 |  3 |         9
2776642 | 2776648 |  4 |         9
2776642 | 2776649 |  5 |         9
2776642 | 2776647 |  6 |         9
2776642 | 2776646 |  7 |         9
      0 | 2776641 |  8 |         0
      0 | 2776642 |  9 |         0
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is also the place to get your homework done :p

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
with newt as (
      select t.*,
             coalesce(n1,
                      (max(n1) over () +
                       row_number() over (partition by n1 order by a1)
                      )
                     ) as new_n1
      from t
     )
select newt.*, tp.new_n1 as parent_n1
from newt left join
     newt newtp
     on newt.p1 = newtp.a1;
```